# Jmeter Mobile app performance testing not working, showing "No Data Connection" in mobile

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm trying to test performance of the mobile apps through physical device using tool Apache Jmeter 5.5. After all the necessary configuration such as proxy setting, setting port number, installing apache jmeter certificate, entering ip address, enabling developer options and usb debugging i'm getting "No Data Connection" in the mobile device and the internet is not working in turn unabling to make request.
Any soultion for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an essential part of "all the necessary configuration" - amending your application [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) to trust JMeter's certificate.

1. add the next line to the [application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element) section of your application [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro)

   ```
   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
   ```
2. create `network_security_config.xml` file in your application [resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) folder and put the following code there

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <network-security-config>
       <debug-overrides>
           <trust-anchors>
               <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
               <certificates src="user"/>
           </trust-anchors>
       </debug-overrides>
   </network-security-config>
   ```
3. build your app in [debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode)
4. replace original .apk with the one you've just built on the device

More information: [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354685999889-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording)

Comment: I followed the steps and configured the emulator. But I'm getting error "your clock is ahead- can't be established because your device's date and time are incorrect" How to fix this? "NET:ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID"

Comment: How about checking that time is the same in the emulator and machine where you're running JMeter? Also the certificate has [validity duration of 7 days](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert) since creation, you might want to extend it, it's controllable via `proxy.cert.validity` [JMeter Property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) (you will need to delete *ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt* and *proxyserver.jks*, restart HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and re-import the certificate in your emulator)

Comment: Samplers are getting recorded for web apps but not being able to record for hybrid apps. When I tried to record samplers for prime video, the app is not even opening showing "no internet connection"